# How to manage css border-top in javascript tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to manage css border-top in javascript tag?

I use this but it does not work

```
    $(".image").stop().animate({"border-top": '1px solid #ddd' ,"padding-top": '5px' ,height: '10px' ,width: '200px' ,opacity: 1}, 100);
```

when I try `padding-top height width opacity` it works , but `border-top` does not work 
How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/oxLtk8Ls/

look it, try

**border-top-width**

```
 $(".image").stop().animate({"border-top-width": '1px' ,"padding-top": '5px' ,height: '10px' ,width: '200px' ,opacity: 1}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to try using `borderTop` as property specification instead of '`border-top`'.

Answer (score 0):

You can only animate numeric properties (in your case `border-width`), so you have to use `border-top-width` (CSS) or `borderTopWidth` (DOM) as key.
If I recall correctly, to animate the border color you have to use jQuery UI.

This is because jQuery doesn't know how to construct a CSS string for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try animating using a set of css property of jQuery.
In addition to that if you want to use color animation then make sure you have included **jQuery UI**

```
  $(".image").stop().animate({borderTopWidth: '1px',  
                              borderTopStyle:'solid',
                              borderTopColor:'red', 
                              "padding-top": '5px', 
                              height: '10px', 
                              width: '200px' 
                             ,opacity: 1}, 1000);
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8cLd4gL/)